# Join two SQL tables on specific field only

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join

Let's say we have the 2 following tables:

[image: TABLE: R]                                      [image: TABLE: T]

How to join the two tables, so that only the `Engineering` row of the 2nd table is added to the first with a `client_count`of `0` or `NULL`. The result shoud look like this:

```
     department      |    clients_count
Engineering          |         NULL
IT Security          |           1
Avertising           |           7
```

Comment: how far have you done? share some code. you could just use left join with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a `left join`:

```
select 
    t2.department,
    t1.clients_count
from t2
left join t1 on t1.department = t2.department
```

Possibly, you would have several records with the same department in `t2` (which seems to store the employees of each department). In that case you could use `distinct` in a subquery, like so:

```
select 
    t2.department,
    t1.clients_count
from (select distinct department from t2) t2
left join t1 on t1.department = t2.department
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a `left join`:

```
select t2.department, t1.clients_count
from table2 t2 left join
     table1 t1
     on t2.department = t1.department;
```